# Windows Forms application that will create another executable file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on a windows forms application, from which user can provide a few configuration. Once, this is done, I want to generate an .exe that will use that configuration and perform specified tasks.

Here, one .exe will be generated out of my main windows forms application.. but, how do I create another .exe that will perform actual tasks?

I hope I have clarified my question. Any leads will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Suhani.

Comment: No, your question is not that clear. If the user only provides configuration data, why creating a new exe every time?

Comment: because based on configuration, that generated exe is supposed to perform the actual task. i.e. user will provide file name and I have operate that file name later on when the user wants.. I need to create exe in a specified path so that user can execute it when required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method gives you great freedom generating any program.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Compile("abc.exe", "Abc");
    Compile("bcd.exe", "Bcd");
}

static void Compile(string fileName, string param1)
{
    var code = "using System;"
        + "public class Program {"
        + "    public static void Main(string[] args)"
        + "    {"
        + "        Console.WriteLine(\"" + param1 + "\");"
        + "    }"
        + "}";

    var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    var options = new CompilerParameters();
    options.GenerateExecutable = true;
    options.OutputAssembly = fileName;
    options.MainClass = "Program";
    provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, code);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tommy !! I will try this method and provide feedback